# Find and list a modified date and time of a file

Tags: linux

I have multiple directories on the server whose names starts with tomcat_
Under this there is a file for example managetest.class

Now I need to get only the modified date and time for that particular file in the below format

Folder name modifieddate

Comment: Are all the `tomcat_*` directories in the same directory?

Comment: `find`'s `-printf` option can print a lot of info, but I'm not sure about the directory and don't have the man page handy.

Answer (score 1):

As Ulrich suggested, you can do it with `find` thus:

```
find "/mydir" -type f -regex ".*/tomcat_.*/managetest.class" -printf "%h %T+\n"
```

UPDATE:

to get the format you require, we can pipe the output through awk:

```
find "/mydir" -type f -path "*/tomcat_*/managetest.class" -printf "%h %T+\n" | awk -F"[ /.]" '{print $(NF-4),$(NF-1)}'
```

The awk statement splits the output up into fields at any of the characters in '[space]/.' - then it prints out the fields that are fourth and first from last which should be the ones you need, so you no longer see the higher level directories, the filename or the split seconds. (I've also switched to `find`'s `-path` instead of `-regex`, but they both achieve the same thing.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir,
I am getting the output as I require

but only one problem

The whole file path is coming in the output

eg:
/home/test/tomcat_ABCD/managetest.class  2015-10-31+11:46:02.0000000000

I only need tomcat_ABCD and date with time in good format
Is this possible.

Comment: I added some piping through awk hopefully this gives you what you need

Answer (score 1):

`cd` to the directory where the `tomcat_*` directories are (they to not need to be all in the same directory), and execute the following command:

```
find . -path "./*tomcat_*managetest.class"
```

This will match, for instance:

```
./b/tomcat_c/managetest.class
./tomcat_a/managetest.class
./tomcat_a/b/managetest.class
```

But not `./b/c/managetest.class`. Let me know if `managetext.class` has to be immediately inside `tomcat_*`.

Now, the complete command to print also the modified date:

```
find . -path "./*tomcat_*managetest.class" -exec stat -c "%n %y" {} \;
```

You can select the fields that you are more interested (like year or time) with awk, writing at the end to the above command something like `| awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3}'`, or, like gogoud suggested, instead of using exec, you can use `find`'s `printf` command.